# Clear timeout after the timer reaches zero

Tags: javascript

This is what I have, I want to clear the timer after it reaches zero and also reload the homepage, if possible probable update mysql database using php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function()
{
    timezone: 'Africa/Lagos';
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "request_rec.php", false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    var timer = document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}, 1000);

if(xmlhttp.responseText < 1)
{
     clearTimeout(timer);
     location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have an interval, so `clearInterval()` would be the relevant function, but the value you pass it would need to be what is returned from `setInterval()`, not a value from your Ajax response.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is setTimeout() instead of setInterval().
Read the difference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).